# Automatically output file name and hard drive writing performance in python

Tags: python, disk

I am writing a python script to delele lines from an input file, so far it looks like:

```
import sys
flag = 1
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as inputfile, open('e:/file_v001.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        if line.strip() == 'BeginModeData Compose':
            flag = 0
        if flag:
            outputfile.write(line)
        if line.strip() == 'EndModuleData':
            flag = 1
```

If e:\file.txt is my inputfile, I dont want to hard code like open('e:/file_v001.txt', 'w'), is there any way to automatically name my outputfile base on inputfile? Or, If I like python to overwrite my original file, what can I do?

Does **outputfile.write(line)** means that python write hard drive 5000 times if the outpufile has 5000 lines? Will it better like this:

```
import sys
flag = 1
buffer = ''
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as inputfile, open('e:/file_v001.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        if line.strip() == 'BeginModeData Compose':
            flag = 0
        if flag:
            buffer += line
        if line.strip() == 'EndModuleData':
            flag = 1
    outputfile.write(buffer)
```

I think python only write hard drive once at this point, but the buffer data will remains in RAM. How do you think?

Futhermore, how to accomplish 'drag and drop' input file instead of manual input command **script.py inputfile outputfile** in windows?

Comment: This appears to be three very different questions. (1) How to choose output file names based on input file names? (2) Do all calls to `write` actually produce separate filesystem write operations or is there buffering? (3) How to do drag and drop in Windows? -- These questions have basically nothing to do with one another. It would be better to ask them separately. Otherwise, e.g., what are you going to do if someone answers one part perfectly but leaves the others untouched?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is three different questions.I am new to stackoverflow, so do I need to ask them separately at this point?

Comment: I'd suggest doing that. Pick one of the three for this one to be about; ask two new ones and edit this one to narrow its focus. (Don't forget to adjust the title as well as the text.)

Comment: The drag-and-drop question is likely to be too broad to make a good SO question unless you already have a Python GUI library/framework in mind.

Comment: And I wouldn't be surprised to find that there are already questions resembling your other two; obviously you shouldn't create a question that's a near-duplicate of an existing one.